# What user should own my Python scripts and application directories?

Tags: python, linux, web-applications, chown

I've been using `chown www-data:www-data -R /path/to/my/django-app/` and simply letting my virtualenv's dirs / files be owned by `root` (since `sudo pip install foo` implies that by default). This just doesn't feel right though. Is this pretty typical, or, should `www-data` only own directories that it can upload files to? If I allow `root` to own everything, my server won't even be able to write `.pyc` files, or will it? I'm clearly quite new to Unix permissions. What is the secure, proper way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way is to compile to bytecode on install so that .pyc files never need to be created on the fly. The rest is basic stuff, like "never use 0777/0666".

Comment: Thanks. So, `root` should own my application directory and virtualenv directory (as well as the files therein)? Should `www-data` own the file uploads directory (i.e., `MEDIA_ROOT`), or should I only give read/write perms to `www-data`, but still keep it in `root`'s hands?

Comment: As much of it as makes sense. Obviously not upload directories or user files (since they would be www-data instead).

Comment: Ok, one more thing if you don't mind: I will `chown root:root -R` everything then (except uploads dir), and then set the permissions on everything to `755`. Does that sound right? Should the directories be something different than the files?

Comment: For most purposes directories should be 0755 and files should be 0644; Python web application scripts are usually read by the interpreter, not directly executed (i.e. `./script.py`).

Comment: Thanks. I've never manually compiled a project, btw. Do you just use `py_compile` and compile every module, or do you simply import all your modules?

Comment: Well, I usually use distutils or setuptools, but `compileall` should work.